# How to send data from silverlight Application to MVC Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application. I added a silverlight app to my MVC project. This Silverlight does record audio using user microphone. Now I have a problem of how to pass recorded audio to MVC action, so I can save this data to a local folder of on the server.

```
this.audioData; // It's byte[]

public void SaveFile()
{
     WebClient net = new WebClient();
     string data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this.audioData, 0, this.audioData.Length);

     net.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("/Home/SaveFile", UriKind.Relative), data);
}
```

I've tried to use `WebClient`, but how to receive this data in Action?

Here's my Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFile(string data)
{

     return View();
}
```

But My data is empty... I know, that I am deferentially doing something wrong. What is the best way to pass my `byte[]` to the MVC Action?

Comment: Use your debugger to check the contents of Request and it's properties in `SaveFile(string data)`. The data may be in the request body instead of being mapped to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // do something 
            // as example try to save file somewhere uploadFile.SaveAs(somewhere);
        }
        return View();
    }
```